# Que es en ejemplo de un palabra abreviada o acortamiento por el cual la gente en su mayoría ha olvidado el original

Tags: español-medieval, origen

La palabra en inglesa por "quincena" (dos semanas) es un acortamiento o acrónimo de la frase ingles por "catorce noches".

La palabra "*fortnight*" (quincena) es un [***portmanteau***](https://en-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Portmanteau?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) de la frase "*fourteen nights*".

Una respuesta a esta pregunta es un solo ejemplo de un par orden: (1. palabra contemporánea, 2. frase antigua).

En la par, la palabra española contemporánea se origina a partir de la frase antigua de mas de una palabra. La frase que es en ejemplo de un palabra el cual la gente en su mayoría ha olvidado el original frase.

La frase podría venir de castellano antiguo, o romance Castellon, o español medieval o espanol tienes mas 50 anos

Answer (score 2):

Me parece recordar que "usted" viene de una abreviación de "vuestra Merced".

Answer (score 0):

Hay miles de ejemplos, basta con indagar en el origen de cada [palabra compuesta](https://www.ejemplos.co/100-ejemplos-de-palabras-compuestas/)

Por ejemplo:

**Astronauta**: Compuesto de astro (V.) y nauta (V.), del latín nauta ‘marinero, navegante’, para designar la persona que navega por el espacio.

**Benefactor**: La palabra benefactor viene del latín, compuesta de bene (bien, como en bendecir), el verbo facere (nos dio hacer) y el sufijo -tor (agente, como en autor y doctor). Se refiere a alguien (-tor) que hace (facere) bien (bene).

**Hojalata**: compuesta con "hoja" y también "lata". Es una palabra yuxtapuesta que se refiere a lámina de hierro o acero cubierta de estaño por las dos caras.

**Vinagre**: vinum (vino) + acre (ácido)

**Tiovivo**: Esteban Fernández, conocido como “el tío Esteban”, propietario de un carrusel infantil de cuatro caballos de juguete en el Paseo de las Delicias, enfermó y fue dado por muerto. Ocurrió que al pasar su cortejo fúnebre precisamente por delante de su negocio, se oyó su voz gritar “¡Estoy vivo!, ¡estoy vivo!”; con lo que la gente pasó a llamar “el Tío Vivo” al propio Esteban y luego a su negocio.

El diario madrileño ABC, que se hizo eco de esta historia el 13 de septiembre de 2015, cuenta que la atracción, hasta entonces llamada “los caballitos”, pasó a llamarse “los caballitos del Tío Vivo” y poco a poco, simplemente, tiovivo. ([Fuente](https://www.elcastellano.org/envios/2021-12-14-000000))

**Pelagatos**: Hay quienes aseguran que la palabra pelagatos surgió en España, durante tiempos duros de hambruna y pobreza, donde algunos podían dedicarse literalmente a pelar gatos para luego comérselos para poder sobrevivir. ([Fuente](https://www.easyespanol.org/blog/word-of-the-day/la-palabra-del-dia-pelagatos/#:%7E:text=Tiene%20como%20sin%C3%B3nimos%20las%20palabras,luego%20com%C3%A9rselos%20para%20poder%20sobrevivir.))